# Simple Audio Amp for FPGA audio to PC

Tags: fpga, audio

I'm working on an FPGA implementation of a retro '80s computer (see http://fpgabee.toptensoftware.com) and am trying to setup some 8-bit audio support.  I'm using a sigma-delta DAC and a R/C low-pass filter.

What I currently have is a 3.3 V pin from the FPGA driving a circuit.

If I connect a pair of iPhone headphones I can hear the audio, it's sounds quite good although the volume is a little low.

What I'd like to do however is connect this to my PC for recording or to pass-through to my speakers.  I tried connecting the above circuit directly to both line-in and microphone sockets on my sound card but the results were terrible.  Nothing audible on the line-in, and very low volume and lots of noise on the microphone socket.

So I'm looking for is a simple circuit (I presume a amp of sorts) that will let me get a clean signal into the PC.  I'm not talking about hi-fi quality stuff here - this is 8-bit audio driving a very simple dac.

Comment: Have you tried a very simple op-amp?

Comment: For the microphone input I think most only like about 100mV in, you might be able to try a divider to attenuate it instead of an amp as well.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I happen to have an opa2314 setting here from another project, but don't know how to hook it up.

Comment: @PeterJ  wouldn't that make it even quieter?  Already on the mic input I have to ramp up the gain in the PC to even hear it.

Comment: That's what TI application note 31 is for.

Comment: @BradRobinson, I was thinking it might be clipping it so much it's no longer audible, sounds like that's not the case though if turning up the gain improves it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Great Thanks!  So if I was to use the non-inverting amp circuit, what sort of gain do you think I should be aiming for?

Comment: It's impossible for me to say. I would (completely) guess 2 to 10; use a pot so you can adjust it, then replace with a fixed value after.

Comment: [LM386 Low Voltage Audio Power Amplifier](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/282/snas545a-56527.pdf) ... not great, but very simple in an 8-pin package.

Comment: You likely need to make an effort to understand the *nature of the problem* before you start throwing building blocks at it.  Have you examine the output with a scope?  Or even plotted the recorded audio data, while playing test signals starts from an extremely quiet sine wave and working up through your trials?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a simple audio interface with volume control, you can do a quick search on internet for such, but if you want recommendation based on personal experience, I would suggest LM4811, which is a simple, low cost and easy to use headphone amplifier from TI.
[image: Typical connection diagram for LM4811]

http://www.ti.com/product/lm4811

If you work for a company, you can register at TI and ask for a couple of samples. They are not easy to solder, but you may ask someone for help to get it on a test board.

Comment: It's not exactly clear that this will solve the actual problem the poster faces.

Comment: @ChrisStratton this will bring the unamplified audio to an amplified line-level. That is exactly what OP wanted (with an extra digital audio control). What is unclear about that?

Comment: It's quite unlikely that is the actual problem.  And no, what you have depicted is not really a line level output, though it might be adapted to one with component changes.